# How to read in Wed Oct 02 09:37:43 BST 2019 to datetime format using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have an excel sheet which is Wed Oct 02 09:37:43 BST 2019  and Wed Oct 02 09:37:43 GMT 2019,
I want to read it in via the format 2019-10-02 09:37:43 (with the time being GMT) in pandas.

Thanks

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['Wed Oct 02 09:37:43 BST 2019'])
                 .str.replace('\bBST\b','GMT'),
               utc=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you can use `parser.parse`
Here what it gives you:

```
date=('Wed Oct 02 09:37:43 BST 2019')
print(parser.parse(date))
out 2019-10-02 09:37:43
```